# Do restriction enzymes on read 3' to 5'?

Tags: molecular-genetics, restriction-enzymes

Every chart of palindromic restriction enzymes I've seen lists their restriction sites from 5' to 3', something like this:

*Eco*R1 cuts GAATTC between the G and A:  
 
          5' NNNGAATTCNNN 3' --> 5' NNNG____ AATTCNNN 3'
          3' NNNCTTAAGNNN 5' --> 3' NNNCTTAA____ GNNN 5'

Will restriction enzymes match and cut a site if it's running antiparallel? For example, will *Eco*R1 cut this sequence?

5' NNNCTTAAGNNN 3'
3' NNNGAATTCNNN 5'

Answer (score 2):

Whatever sequence (plus direction) is target, so enzyme will cut. In your example "correct" and "antiparallel" sequences are two different sites.

Actually, your example of 5'-CTTAAG-3' is cut by [AflII](https://www.neb.com/products/r0520-aflii) enzyme.

Comment: Additionally, the definition of "palindrome" means that it does not matter which direction the read is in, as either direction is identical.

Comment: Another way to think about it is to look at the 3-D structure of GAATTC, I believe there is also a 3-D structure of the Eco RI enzyme. The sequence CTTAAG cannot be superimposed on top of GAATTC--well, when you superimpose them they don't align significantly. Likewise ds GAATTC fits perfectly into the enzyme active site while ds CTTAAG will fit, but poorly.

Comment: @mdperry that is what behind (in some part) specificity :)